Can't connect to Arduino Nano 33 BLE while MicroPython file is running
I am using a Arduino Nano 33 BLE and I'm using MicroPython to write code for my board using Arduino Lab for MicroPython. I uploaded a file with the name main.py to my Arduino to test if it would work and it does. But the problem is that now it won't stop and I can't connect to it while the file is running (it keeps running because of infinite loop in the code). And if I change it to bootloader mode, Arduino Lab detects it but won't connect. It will connect to the Arduino IDE in the bootloader mode, so this should also work. If anybody is able to help out it would be greatly appreciated.
PS: the code that is in main.py is just blinking the RGB

change your sketch so that it has some serial output

Just use OpenMV to connect to the Arduino Nano and update the firmware, there will be a toggleable option to erase the internal file system. Maybe also try reinstalling Arduino Lab for Micropython.
